# Weird behaviour when selecting from database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Here is my function

```
    function checkAvailability(){
//check
  $session = $_COOKIE["PHPSESSID"];
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM Account  A INNER JOIN User U ON U.ID = A.USER_ID WHERE U.SESSION_ID = '$session';";

echo $sql;
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
 .
 .
 .

}else{
  echo "invalid user.";
}
}
```

this produces:

```
SELECT * FROM Account A INNER JOIN User U ON U.ID = A.USER_ID WHERE U.SESSION_ID = '9fqknqhc5usp3ngsjvmv8kih66'
```

and also goes in the else branch in the code

```
invalid user
```

---

Copy pasting this exact statement **works** on my MySQL database.

I'm wondering whats going wrong, I've checked that i'm using `mysqli` everywhere but still i'm getting
 **0 results**

Additionally,

my `SESSION_ID` field is unique.

Comment: i would have used the function `session_id()` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php) to get the session id instead off `$_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']`

Comment: Ok but it is the Same result??

Comment: Debug.... `var_dump(mysqli_num_rows($result));`

Comment: (1) Use parameters rather than munging the query string.  (2) Leave out the semicolon.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Thanks for info, result was `NULL`

Comment: Nice info, but im not yet at refactoring, It's not really answering my question @GordonLinoff

Comment: Turn on all the error reporting mechanisms and check mysqli_error.

Comment: @har-wradim no `mysqli_error`

Comment: NULL likely means that $result is not a mysqli_result: again, [make sure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438060#5438125) you see all potential errors.